# Polymer class binding issue

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

I am working on a polymer project. In one of my modules i see that in paper-badge element few classes are getting added dynamically.

```
<paper-badge for="document" class="style-scope cvs-badge-common x-scope paper-badge-6" tabindex="0" role="status" aria-label="!">
<div class="badge style-scope paper-badge">
  <iron-icon class="style-scope paper-badge x-scope iron-icon-2" hidden="">
  </iron-icon>
  <span id="badge-text" class="style-scope paper-badge">!</span>
</div>
```

from the above code, some classes are getting added like paper-badge-6 iron-con-2 to some elements. I want to know from where these classes gets added.

There are few more elements in the loop which also get added with similar classes like paper-badge-7 etc.

I searched the entire codebase but did not find anything.

When I inspect the element I also see the CSS styles written for these paper-badge-6 class but in the code there is no code for this class.

Need to find how this works.

Thanks,
UD

Answer (score 1):

That's the shadow DOM adding those classes via the polymer elements you're using. Here's some information on what the 
[Shadow DOM](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/) is and here's how to [style it](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling).